# Changing button text through JS?

Tags: javascript, squarespace

I'm using Squarepace.

I'm trying to change the word 'authenticate' [here](http://www.mccannshowandtell.com/)

This is the script:

```
document.title = "McCann Show & Tell - Please enter the password :)";
document.body.style.background = "#f7a2cc  url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46025079/pattern.jpg') repeat";
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.getElementById("yui_3_17_2_1_1418836557893_299").value = "hello";
}, false);
```

This is the part that atttempts to change the button text

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.getElementById("yui_3_17_2_1_1418836557893_299").value = "hello";
}, false);
```

I can't seem to get it working

Comment: I think that button `id` changes frequently. So you can't rely on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` of that button constantly changes, so you need to use a different selector.
You could try:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]')[0].value = 'hello';
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName('saveAndClose')[0].value = 'hello';
```